# fetch data from a table and save it in another table

Tags: python, html, flask

i want to save data from table into another table. i am using flask,  it keeps getting me this error >
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'studentTFQuestion'

i tried to make the fetch into  &  tags but still no success. i guess because these tags inside  because i am using table format thus, it cannot read  &  tags.

is there a way to save the inputs other than this way?

this is test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
<h2>Answer The Following Question</h2>
<form action = "{{ request.path }}" method="POST">

    <br>
 <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
         <thead>
            <tr  style="border: 20px solid black ;">
               <th  style="border: 1px solid black ;">TF Question</th>
               <th  style="border: 1px solid black ;">TF Answer</th>
               <th  style="border: 1px solid black ;">MCQ Question</th>
               <th  style="border: 1px solid black ; display:none;">MCQ Answer</th>
                <th  style="border: 1px solid black ;">Option A</th>
                <th  style="border: 1px solid black ;">Option B</th>
                <th  style="border: 1px solid black ;">Option C</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
            {% for question in quickQuizQuestions %}
               <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                   <td  style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" id="studentTFQuestion" value=" {{ question.TFquestion }}" readonly></td>
                  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                      True <input type="radio" id="T" name="TFquestion" value="T">
                      False <input type="radio" id="F" name="TFquestion" value="F">
                      </td>
                   <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" id="MCQquestionTd" value="{{ question.MCQquestion }}" readonly></td>
                  <td style="border: 1px solid black; display:none;">{{ question.MCQanswer }}</td>
                   <td style="border: 1px solid black;">(A) <input type="radio" id="a" name="MCQquestion" value="A">{{ question.OptionA }}</td>
                   <td style="border: 1px solid black;">(B) <input type="radio" id="b" name="MCQquestion" value="B">{{ question.OptionB }}</td>
                   <td style="border: 1px solid black;">(C) <input type="radio" id="c" name="MCQquestion" value="C">{{ question.OptionC }}</td>
               </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="studentSubmit" name="studentSubmit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is app.py

```
#questions table
class quickQuizQuestions(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, TFquestion, TFanswer, MCQquestion, MCQanswer, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC):
        self.TFquestion = TFquestion
        self.TFanswer = TFanswer
        self.MCQquestion = MCQquestion
        self.MCQanswer = MCQanswer
        self.OptionA = OptionA
        self.OptionB = OptionB
        self.OptionC = OptionC
    id = db.Column('question_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    TFquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    TFanswer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    MCQquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    MCQanswer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    OptionA = db.Column(db.String(1))
    OptionB = db.Column(db.String(1))
    OptionC = db.Column(db.String(1))

#students answers table
class studentAnswerTable(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, TFquestion, studentAnswer, MCQquestion, Option):
        self.TFquestion = TFquestion
        self.studentAnswer = studentAnswer
        self.MCQquestion = MCQquestion
        self.Option = Option
        # answers=[studentAnswer('{{ question.TFquestion }}', 'TFquestion', '{{ question.MCQquestion }}', 'MCQquestion')]
        # table = studentAnswer('answers')
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # student_id = password
    TFquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    studentAnswer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    MCQquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    Option = db.Column(db.String(1))

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
     if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['studentSubmit']:
           question = studentAnswerTable(request.form['studentTFQuestion'], request.form['TFquestion'], request.form['MCQquestionTd'], request.form['MCQquestion'])
           db.session.add(question)
           db.session.commit()
           flash('Record was successfully added')
           return render_template("studentAnswer.html")

        else:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')

     return render_template("test.html", quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.order_by(-quickQuizQuestions.id).limit(1).all())
```

Comment: share the full stack of the error please.

Comment: Are you aware that ` <td  style="border: 1px solid black;"><input type="text" id="studentTFQuestion" value=" {{ question.TFquestion }}" readonly></td>` is creating MANY input fields with the same id?

Comment: @balderman no and i don't think i understand your question